# Got "Insufficient Permission" in Google Contact CardDav Synchronization

Tags: google-contacts-api

I would like to implement google carddav synchronization.
I have already implemented google caldav synchronization with OAuth2.0.
But When I am going to sync with Google CardDav, I got "Insufficient Permission."
Are there any expert google developer who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

1. Have you enabled the APIs on Google API Console when creating the token for your application? Maybe you need to enable CalDAV API in addition to Contacts API?
2. Are you asking for a sufficient scope when requesting the OAuth token?

But honestly, I'd go with [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) or the newer [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/) to synchronize the contacts, because:

1. With CardDAV, there is always going to be some disparity with how Google Contacts work and how CardDAV is designed to work.
2. As far as I know, there's not much incentive to improve the Google's implementation of CalDAV/CardDAV, although are relevant issues to fix (see the issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=caldav - not much happening there)
3. Google Contacts API / People API is actively supported and official libraries are provided for Java, .Net and Python.